# How to find the directory an AutoIt file is being run from?

Tags: autoit, explorer

How can I make an AutoIt file that returns its own current path when it is run on Windows 7?

I want to have the program check to see if it is in a given directory, and if it isn't, make a copy of itself in that directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Documentation - Macros](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm):

> `@ScriptDir` Directory containing the running script. Only includes a trailing backslash when the script is located in the root of a drive.
>
> `@ScriptFullPath` Equivalent to `@ScriptDir & "\" & @ScriptName`

Example:

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>

Global Const $g_sDirTarget = 'C:\foldername'

If Not (@ScriptDir = $g_sDirTarget) Then

   FileCopy(@ScriptFullPath, $g_sDirTarget, $FC_NOOVERWRITE + $FC_CREATEPATH)

EndIf
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the macros `@ScriptDir`

Refer to Official Autoit - [Macros help](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm):